# Different semantic of comparison intrinsic instructions in avx512?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx, avx512

With sse2 or avx comparison operations were returning bitmasks of all zeros or all ones (e.g. _mm_cmpge_pd returns a __m128d.

I cannot find an equivalent with avx512. Comparison operations seems to only return short bitmasks. Has there been a fundamental change in semantic or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the semantics are a bit different in AVX512. The comparison instructions return the results in mask registers. This has a couple advantages:

- The (8) mask registers are entirely separate from the `[xyz]mm` register set, so you don't waste a vector register for the comparison result.
- There are masked versions of nearly the entire AVX512 instruction set, allowing you a lot of flexibility with how you use the comparison results.

It does require slightly different code versus a legacy SSE/AVX implementation, but it isn't too bad.

**Edit:** If you want to emulate the old behavior, you could do something like this:

```
// do comparison, store results in mask register
__mmask8 k = _mm512_cmp_pd_mask(...);
// broadcast a mask of all ones to a vector register, then use the mask
// register to zero out the elements that have a mask bit of zero (i.e.
// the corresponding comparison was false)
__m512d k_like_sse = _mm512_maskz_mov_pd(k, 
    (__m512d) _mm512_maskz_set1_epi64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL));
```

There might be a more optimal way to do this, but I'm relatively new to using AVX512 myself. The mask of all ones could be precalculated and reused, so you're essentially just adding in one extra masked move instruction to generate the vector result that you're looking for.

**Edit 2:** As suggested by Peter Cordes in the comment below, you can use `_mm512_movm_epi64()` instead to simplify the above even more:

```
// do comparison, store results in mask register
__mmask8 k = _mm512_cmp_pd_mask(...);
// expand the mask to all-0/1 masks like SSE/AVX comparisons did
__m512d k_like_sse = (__m512d) _mm512_movm_epi64(k);
```

Comment: If you have a need to save the intermediate results, what was before a vector of double with funny values, now is a vector of single bits. This is a nightmarish refactoring! Vector containers sizes change. Loop peeling logic change. All use cases of these bitmask for doing ops like x & y, wher x is a double and y is a bitmask, change. Anyway, thanks, that is the right answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something like that, at least as a temporary solution. Perhaps with blend_pd. Need to experiment on what is more efficient.

Comment: Probably this: _mm512_maskz_mov_pd

Comment: Yes, that's what I would use. I fixed a couple typos in my example.

Comment: @Fabio These changes are unfortunate costs of this low level of programming. But once it's properly written, the raw instruction count for code that uses this sort of stuff will likely drop significantly. Mainly from losing all the bitwise instructions which get fused away into the embedded masking. The only issue I've ever run into with the new system is running out of mask registers.

Comment: There's an AVX512DQ (or AVX512BW for narrow elements) instruction for converting a `k` mask into a 0 / -1 vector: [`__m512i _mm512_movm_epi64(__mmask16 )` / `VPMOVM2Q zmm1, k1`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPMOVM2B_VPMOVM2W_VPMOVM2D_VPMOVM2Q).  Use that instead of `maskz_mov_pd` so you don't need an all-ones constant in the first place.  Or better just use masks the way they're meant to be used whenever possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't seen that one. AVX512 is so large, it can be hard to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: @JasonR no kidding!  For the reverse direction (sign bit -> mask like `pmovmskb`), there are integer instructions like `vpmovq2m` (again AVX512DQ / BW, so not on KNL), but for FP there's only AVX512DQ [VFPCLASSPS / PD](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VFPCLASSPD) (which doesn't differentiate between -NaN and +NaN, but does for every other case including -0 and +0.  Of course you can use integer instructions on FP data, but I don't think FPCLASSPS is any slower on Skylake, and integer might have bypass latency.  Or you can just use an AVX512F integer `VPCMPQ` against zero.

Comment: @PeterCordes Without having measured it, I'm not so sure `FPCLASS` is necessarily a fast instruction since it probably hits the FMA unit - which is 4 cycles across the board. But I can't tell from looking at `InstLatx64` since they don't do latencies across register domains and the throughput is limited by the mask port.